# Do you have to keg your brew in order to add CO2?

Tags: co2

Can I add Co2 to a fermentation tank or to a brightening tank and than bottle it or attach a line to the tap or do I have to put it in a keg?

Answer (score 3):

Generally: no; most homebrewer-scale fermentation and bright tanks are not rated for pressure, though it really depends on what sort of vessel you're using. Some people do ferment directly in a keg, and use a [spunding valve](//homebrew.stackexchange.com/search?q=spunding+valve) to naturally retain CO₂ directly from the fermentation process, such that the beer can directly be served or bottled.

Comment: The spunding valve trick is pretty slick! You can rack from primary fermentation to a pressure safe vessel like a cornie keg and use the gasses produced in this secondary fermentation to naturally carbonate. Priming sugar can be added to get the carbs you need.

Here is a DIY Spunding Valve write-up from BYO:  http://byo.com/color/item/397-build-your-own-spunding-valve-to-carbonate-in-the-keg

Answer (score 1):

You can also add fermentable sugars to a bottle or keg to carbonate the beer. You do not have to carbonate in a keg.